# ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate retryCount. why?

Tags: c#, ip, webrequest

BindIPEndPointDelegate Including a parameter called retryCount that said the times of trys for this connection.

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.bindipendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx):

> retryCount
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The number of times this delegate was called for a specified connection.

and:

> If the .NET Framework cannot bind the returned IPEndPoint to the ServicePoint after Int32.MaxValue attempts, an OverflowException is thrown.

so the classic code like:

```
IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
{
    if (retryCount > 5)
        return null;
    return ...
}
```

This design shows that there is likely to be needed more attempting, so that the developer needs to act to prevent an endless loop in case the supplied IP is not correct.

Is it right? that is, there is often a failure in the first bind try, and repeat trys can help?

Comment: I would imagine that if it fails the first time, you can iterate retry count and try a different ip address on subsequent tries.